# How does `Cow::Owned` implemented the `FnOnce`?

Tags: rust

This example works fine.

```rs
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let a = Some("Hello");
    let b: Option<Cow<&'static str>> = a.map(Cow::Owned);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

The Option map requires the param must implement `FnOnce(T) -> U`:

```rs
pub const fn map<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<U>
where
    F: ~const FnOnce(T) -> U,
    F: ~const Destruct,
{
    match self {
        Some(x) => Some(f(x)),
        None => None,
    }
}
```

I want to figure out how `Cow::Owned` implement the `FnOnce`. I have searched the source code and found nothing helpful.

Any idea about this?

Comment: `Cow::Owned` is a constructor for the `Owned` enum variant, so it works the same as `String::new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every tuple struct or tuple enum variant with public members is also a free-standing function:

```rust
pub struct A(pub u8);

// creates essentially

pub fn A_fn(one: u8) {
    A(one) // returns the struct
}
```

Every free-standing `fn` falls under the `Fn` category. `FnMut` and `FnOnce` are pretty much only ever applicable to closures.

Any closure which is categorized under `Fn` can be used in a place requiring `FnMut` or `FnOnce`. Any closure which is categorized under `FnMut` can be used in a place requiring `FnOnce`, but NOT in a place requiring `Fn`. Any function or closure which is categorized under `FnOnce` can ONLY be used in a place requiring just `FnOnce`.

In this way, when you see a `Fn` bound, it's actually the opposite in terms of restriction. `FnOnce` is actually the *most permissive* bound:

- `: Fn` means that only `Fn` closures can be used there
- `: FnMut` means that only `Fn` or `FnMut` closures can be used there
- `: FnOnce` means that `Fn`, `FnMut`, or `FnOnce` closures can be used there

`Cow::Owned` is a tuple enum variant with only public members, so can be used as if it were `fn(B) -> Cow<'_, B>`. And since `Fn` can be used where there's a `FnOnce` bound, it's accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Also there's a short albeit burried note in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#enum-values) "the name of each enum variant that we define also becomes a function that constructs an instance of the enum. [..] We automatically get this constructor function defined as a result of defining the enum." ([rust-lang/book#800](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/800))